# .NET System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController x86 Native Memory Leak

Tags: .net, memory-leaks

Using the below code and building to x86 the process uses more and more memory over time. It seems most ServiceController getters such as Status or ServiceType will cause the leak when accessed after a Refresh(), but DisplayName does not. I've let it run for ~25 minutes and it was at around 450MB "Process Memory" in Visual Studio. I made a memory dump using DebugDiag and analysed it and it shows  350MB in "Native Heaps":

[DebugDiag Virtual Memory Summary](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EVSRF.png)

And this is the Heap Summary showing the offending heap with name "Microsoft VC Runtime Heap (private)":

[Heap Summary](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8AYOx.png)

I re-ran the program and analysed a dump made after it was only running for 10 seconds and all the "virtual memory details" was nearly identical except native heaps was only at 10MB. This occurs in debug and release builds on x86 but does not occur in x64. I've only tried targeting .NET 4.5.2 and 4.6 which both show the leak. This is on Windows 7 SP1 64-bit. Is this a bug in the .NET code or is there something I can do with the code or my environment to prevent the leak in x86?

```
namespace ConsoleApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (var s = new System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController("AudioSrv"))
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    s.Refresh();
                    var st = s.Status;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

edit: I've copied the release binaries that show the problem on my win7 ultimate sp1 x64 machine to a win7 pro x64 sp1 VM and this second machine doesn't show the leak. Using Process Explorer I can see that the .NET Assemblies are all the same and the same version (they say NativeImages_V4.0.30319_32 on both machines), but when I go to Threads on each machine the steady state looks very different between the two:

[No memory leak win7 pro sp1 x64](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ugotb.png)

[Memory leak win7 ultimate sp1 x64](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wJ7BA.png)